# Hangman game in Java issue with incorrect guess

Tags: java

I am having an issue with a hangman game I am trying to complete in java just for my own learning. My problem is that currently in my code the number of attempts always counts down no matter if you're right or wrong per guess. So basically you have only 10 goes to figure out the word and then game over.

What I want is that if the guess is correct then the number of attempts stays as the current number and only when I get the guess wrong then does it count down by 1.

I want to know how to implement this as I am struggling to convert my code to do this:

Below is the whole code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random random = new Random();
        String[] movieList = {"The Simpsons Movie", "Batman Begins", "Terminator"};

        boolean weArePlaying = true;
        while (weArePlaying) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to Guess The Movie Game");

            char[] randomWordToGuess = movieList[random.nextInt(movieList.length)].toLowerCase().toCharArray();
            int wordLength = randomWordToGuess.length;
            char[] playerGuess = new char[wordLength];

            for (int i = 0; i < playerGuess.length; i++) {
                    playerGuess[i] = '_';
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < randomWordToGuess.length; i++) {
                if (randomWordToGuess[i] == ' ') {
                    playerGuess[i] = ' ';
                }
            }

            boolean wordCompleted = false;
            int attempts = 10;

            while (!wordCompleted && attempts != 0) {
                System.out.println("Current guess: ");
                printArray(playerGuess);
                System.out.println("Number of attempts left: " + attempts);
                System.out.println("Enter a letter");
                char input = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
                attempts--;

                if (input == '-') {
                    weArePlaying = false;
                    wordCompleted = true;
                }

                else {
                        for (int i = 0; i < randomWordToGuess.length; i++) {
                            if (randomWordToGuess[i] == input) {
                                playerGuess[i] = input;
                            }
                        }


                    if (isTheWordCompleted(playerGuess)) {
                        wordCompleted = true;
                        System.out.println("You Won!!!");
                        System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (yes/no)");
                    }
                }

            }

            if (!wordCompleted) {
                System.out.println("You ran out of movieList. Game Over");
                System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (yes/no)");
                String anotherGame = scanner.nextLine();
                if (anotherGame.equals("no")) {
                    weArePlaying = false;
                } else if (anotherGame.equals("yes")) {
                    weArePlaying = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (yes/no)");
                }
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Game Over");
    }

    public static void printArray(char[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
           System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static boolean isTheWordCompleted(char[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == '_') {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only put `attempts--;` if the guess is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are decrementing the attempt count whenever there is an input:

```
char input = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
attempts--; //remove this line from here
```

Modify the part where you check the user input as such:

```
Boolean flag = false;
for (int i = 0; i < randomWordToGuess.length; i++) {
    if (randomWordToGuess[i] == input) {
       playerGuess[i] = input;
       flag = true; //user input is correct
       break;
    }
}

if (!flag){ //user input is wrong
   attempt--;
}
```